# Error Report- SQL Error :ORA-01722

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd like to correct this error message I have been getting, when I try to execute this Command:

```
INSERT INTO SCHEDULE (SCHEDULE_ID, ARRV_TIME, DEP_TIME, BUS_TRANSFERS, BUS_ID, WEEK_DAY)
VALUES (SEQ_SCHEDULE.NEXTVAL, '4', '1', '10', '11', '2');
```

Error starting at line : 1 in command -

> Error report - SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number 01722. 00000 -
>   "invalid number" *Cause: The specified number was invalid. *Action:
>   Specify a valid number.

The table I created to execute this command is:

```
CREATE TABLE SCHEDULE (
    SCHEDULE_ID NUMERIC NOT NULL
    ,ARRV_TIME NUMERIC NOT NULL
    ,DEP_TIME NUMERIC NOT NULL
    ,BUS_TRANSFERS VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL
    ,BUS_ID NUMERIC NOT NULL 
    ,TRAVEL_DIRECTION VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL 
    ,WEEK_DAY INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

Unfortunately, I had to Alter the table just to see if things will work, but to no avail.

```
ALTER TABLE SCHEDULE DISABLE ALL TRIGGERS;
ALTER TABLE SCHEDULE MODIFY ARRV_TIME VARCHAR(20);
ALTER TABLE SCHEDULE MODIFY DEP_TIME VARCHAR(20);
ALTER TABLE SCHEDULE MODIFY SCHEDULE_ID NUMERIC(20);
ALTER TABLE SCHEDULE MODIFY ARRV_TIME NUMERIC(20);
ALTER TABLE SCHEDULE MODIFY DEP_TIME NUMERIC(20);
ALTER TABLE SCHEDULE MODIFY BUS_TRANSFERS NUMBER(20);
ALTER TABLE SCHEDULE DROP COLUMN TRAVEL_DIRECTION;
```

In actuality, I have tried all avenues to correct this error, but no luck. I did change the numbers, put them in quotes; and several others, but still cannot get any luck.

Comment: Rspect the data format,no string for numeric or integer,string for VARCHAR

Comment: Please run these queries, then [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33890847/edit) your question and append the results inside ...

(1) `select owner, column_name, data_type, default_length, hidden_column, virtual_column from all_tab_cols where table_name = 'SCHEDULE';`

(2) `select owner, object_type from all_objects where object_name = 'SCHEDULE';`

(3) `select owner, trigger_name, trigger_type, triggering_event, table_owner from all_triggers where table_name = 'SCHEDULE';`

(4) `select owner, constraint_name, constraint_type from all_constraints where table_name = 'SCHEDULE';`

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your response. Actually, I am a beginner to this game, so what will be next after I am done running all the (4) queries suggested.

Comment: add result queries in your question so we can see them

Answer (score 1):

Your table `schedule` have `not null` field `travel_direction`. And you try insert data without value for this field. It is must throw follows exeption:

> ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCHEDULE"."TRAVEL_DIRECTION")

Other looks normal.